# How to make element position fixed but also go off the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a right menu in a browser window:

```
___________________________
                   | Right |
        content    | Menu  |
                   |       |
                   |       |
                   |       |
                   |       |
                   |       |
                   |       |
                   |       |
___________________|_______|
```

I want the menu to be fixed  so that the user sees the same thing as he/she scrolls down.  So I set the position:fixed for the right menu.

However, I also want the menu to not be seen if the window is too small. i.e. window should display full content before right menu.

Like this:

```
_________________________
                   | Ri |
        content    | Me |
                   |    |
                   |    |
                   |    |
                   |    |
                   |    |
                   |    |
                   |    |
___________________|____|
```

Is there a way to do this in pure css? If not, a very simple js fix?

Edit:

I have a related question, so I didn't feel like the need to create another question:

I have a fixed width for the right menu, but I need the left content to auto adjust its width accordingly (fill up left side). Is there a way to do this in css and keep the above functionality?

Comment: does *content* get resized horizontally when you resize the browser ?

Comment: no, the content is NOT set to height:100%

Comment: i mean its width (*not its height*), how do you determine the width of the content?

Comment: I just added to my question, but currently the width is set to 80%, which given pebbl's answer, I could just set left:80%. HOWEVER, my right menu is set to 240px, so there is a blank right gap if I do this, therefore, I need to left content to fill up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the dimensions of your content you can use the following instead:

```
position:fixed; left:800px;
```

rather than:

```
position:fixed; right:0;
```

If say your content was 800px wide. This means your calculation is working from the left and the menu will push off screen if the users window is smaller than that.

#### update

As it seems that your requirements are the following:

- You have a content region that has a minimum width specified.
- You need your menu to scroll with the user.
- You need your menu to appear attached to the right, until the menu would encroach on the minimum width of your content.

I would recommend using JavaScript to solve this problem, you can achieve it in pure CSS but by placing your menu into a fixed layer that covers the whole page. Whilst the logic here works in modern browsers — due to z-indexing the content above the menu-container — I would hate to see what older user agents would make of it:

#### pure css version

**css**

```
/* make sure our content doesn't collapse too small */
.content { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  min-width: 700px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}
/* place our menu container across the entire page */
.menu-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
/* a layer that mimics what our content does */
.menu-offset  {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 700px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
/* finally the menu attached to the right of the menu offset */
.menu-content { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%; 
  left: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

**markup**

```
<div class="content">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis 
  adipiscing magna sed ipsum convallis vel fringilla nibh viverra.
  Nulla et ligula vel urna scelerisque imperdiet a et lectus.
  Nunc commodo, nibh id blandit mollis, leo quam eleifend urna,
  at rhoncus turpis justo sit amet erat. Quisque tempus nunc 
  vitae eros fringilla eget imperdiet neque tincidunt. Donec 
  ac posuere diam. Nam nibh nibh, sollicitudin non blandit ut, 
  auctor in dolor. Nullam lobortis condimentum consequat. 
  </p>
  <p>
  Maecenas at orci massa, quis congue mauris. Vivamus varius 
  tincidunt nunc, eget <a href="#canyouclickthis">pellentesque arcu 
  faucibus</a> ac. Suspendisse rhoncus orci eu felis consectetur 
  rutrum. Nullam sed mauris eros. Nunc dignissim, libero dapibus 
  consectetur lobortis, ante urna faucibus dui, vel luctus metus 
  leo id magna. Pellentesque mi ligula, commodo ac pellentesque 
  et, auctor sed neque. Phasellus dapibus tellus faucibus dui 
  vehicula hendrerit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique 
  senectus et netus et malesuada 
  fames ac turpis egestas.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-offset">
    <nav class="menu-content">Menu</nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the above I would expect older browsers to either render so that you wont be able to interact with anything in the content div — please see the `#canyouclickthis` link — or to not support `position:fixed` properly anyway:

http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

#### update 2

Ah, just spotted your comment with regards to `80%` width. A modification to the above could work for this, however, it's probably best to avoid using a percentage width when you have a fixed-width menu — especially with the conditions you are specifying — and rely on min and max-width instead. Either that or use a menu with a percentage width rather than fixed.

Depending on how you have/want your markup set up, the following could work. This approach counts on the fact that if you don't specify `left`, `top`, `bottom` or `right` the layer should stay where it is placed (not 100% true in older browsers). You may find you have to define dimensions for the `.menu` layer for less modern UAs. This solution has the added benefit of not covering the entier page in a fixed layer :)

```
.content        { position:relative; width:80%; min-width: 800px; float:left; }
.menu-container { position:absolute; left:100%; top:0; }
.menu-content   { position: fixed; width:20%; height:100%; background:#ddd; }

<div class="content">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis 
  adipiscing magna sed ipsum convallis vel fringilla nibh viverra.
  Nulla et ligula vel urna scelerisque imperdiet a et lectus.
  Nunc commodo, nibh id blandit mollis, leo quam eleifend urna,
  at rhoncus turpis justo sit amet erat. Quisque tempus nunc 
  vitae eros fringilla eget imperdiet neque tincidunt. Donec 
  ac posuere diam. Nam nibh nibh, sollicitudin non blandit ut, 
  auctor in dolor. Nullam lobortis condimentum consequat. 
  </p>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <nav class="menu-content">Menu</nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again it would be best to test this in the likes of Internet Explorer as I don't have access to that particular User agent atm.

Comment: yes, that's right, but unfortunately, I don't know the width of the window

Comment: @Derek You shouldn't need to know the width of the window, just the width you want your content to wrap at. In order for your menu to push off right when the window is too small you'd need to have some kind of width set for your content.. however this becomes much more tricky if your content has the possibility of a mininum and maximum width. If the latter is the case you'd be better off using js to modify the `left` offset inline with your responsive content's current width.

Comment: ah yes, you're right, but I don't know the width of the content either. sorry should have been more clear

Comment: @Derek I've added an update with a pure css solution, however it should be tested across all your target user agents to make sure there are no ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, give the `content` element a `margin-right` or `padding-right` equal to the menu width

So

```
.menu{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;
   width: 240px; /*the fixed width you want*/
}

.content{ /*assuming there is a wrapper element*/
   margin-right:240px; /*same as fixed width of menu*/
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MMnhZ/

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you could calculate the width of the window and the width of your content then assign it to the left value of the menu.

```
var leftPosition = ($('#wrapper').width() / 2 ) + ($(window).width() / 2);

$('#menu').css("left", leftPosition);
```

Use $(window).resize(); to recalculate it if the window changes. Add an if/else statement to make sure it stays above a certain amount and you're set.

Here's a [jsFiddle showing the result](http://jsfiddle.net/yhyEJ/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: *the OP has not stated that he uses jQuery*

Comment: Gaby's right. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it to say he needs to include it